# How to use batch to run RNN model with texts that have different length in each row?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, data-mining, torch

I want to use `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence` in pytorch to deal with this problem, But I dont kown how to get torch variable when it has different size in the last dimension?

```
torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(input, lengths, batch_first=False, enforce_sorted=True)
input can be of size T x B x * where T is the length of the longest sequence (equal to lengths[0]), B is the batch size, and * is any number of dimensions (including 0)
```

[pack_padded_sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence.html)

I will get errors if I run the following code.

```
x_torch = torch.from_numpy(np.ones((2, 3)))
y_torch = torch.from_numpy(np.ones((2, 5)))
ans_torch = torch.cat([x_torch, y_torch], dim = 0)

# ouput
RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Got 3 and 5 in dimension 1 at c:\a\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\aten\src\th\generic/THTensorMoreMath.cpp:1333
```

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I learnd from this code, should complete the torch with zero or other any digit that have no meaning before using `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence`

[pad_packed_demo](https://gist.github.com/Tushar-N/dfca335e370a2bc3bc79876e6270099e)